# Get Row Selected from UITableView?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin iOS app I have the following code:

```
public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        new UIAlertView("Row Selected", TableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK").Show();
    }
}
```

This successfully sends an alert whenever a new cell is selected by the user, however I want to be able to call this method, or a similar method, from within my `ViewController`. Basically so that I could click a button and it would return the currently selected cell.

I know that what I need is the `TableItems[indexPath.Row]` so is there anyway I could modify the `RowSelected` method further so that the value from `TableItems[indexPath.Row]` could be used again somewhere else?

Comment: You could save selected cell into an instance variable in RowSelected method to keep last selected index. Then you can refer to it from controller to retrieve value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that TableItems is an array that you have created.  Create a variable to store the index.  When the RowSelected method is called set the variable index to the value of the indexPath.Row.  Whenever the method is called it will reset the value depending on which row was clicked and now you have the value and can use it elsewhere in your program

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else who comes across this problem, this is how I did it:

```
public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    public static string SelectedRow;

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        new UIAlertView("Row Selected", TableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK").Show();

        SelectedRow = TableItems[indexPath.Row];
    }
}
```

Then whenever I need to use the currently selected item, simply call `TableSource.SelectedRow`

Comment: I hope no one actually does that.